# How do I plot a 2D array graph in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a little bit of trouble in creating a graph using 2D array data in python.

I have a txt file which holds data like this:

```
0 2 4 6 8
-1 -2 -1 2 4
0 1 0 -1 0
1 3 5 7 6
0 1 -1 -3 2
1 -1 1 1 0
```

(this is shortened, my actual file is 100*10000

So essentially a 5x6 array.

I would like the x axis to be the total number of elements in each array which is always going to be a fixed limit of 5.
The Y axis needs to be the actual data point from the txt file.
Which leaves 6 lines in total being created.

Below is a quickly drawn photo in paint:
[Image here (low score, cannot embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOW7J.png)
So Y = data value, X = length of each individual array and the lines are how many total arrays their are.

I would like to use this style, however if possible make the line width 1px as there are going to be roughly 10,000 lines drawn.
http://matplotlib.org/examples/style_sheets/plot_fivethirtyeight.html

I have had a try with some of the code, and this is where I got stuck, I could read in the data and store it in some kind of array, but then was unable to use that for making the graph. (Top part is my code for reading it in, bottom part is the example code from the fivethirtyeight style.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('thisone.txt') as file:
    array2d = [[int(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in file]


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10)

with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + x + np.random.randn(50))
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + 0.5 * x + np.random.randn(50))
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(x) + 2 * x + np.random.randn(50))


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you read in the data, iterate over the rows in the data and plot a graph row vs. range(len(row)).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('thisone.txt') as file:
    array2d = [[int(digit) for digit in line.split()] for line in file]

with plt.style.context('fivethirtyeight'):
    for row in array2d:
        plt.plot(xrange(len(row)), row)

plt.show()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Only had to change xrange to range due to python version. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there an easy way of creating a line of best fit/average line? So one solid line starting the middle (0) and going along the x axis which shows if its a negative or positive trend?

Comment: Add a row to at the end of array2d, which has all zeros.